# Flutter play custom sound using audioplayers 0.7.7?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

```
pubspec.yaml
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/Images/1.png
    - assets/Images/MP3.mp3

Test.dart

  Widget localAsset() {
    return _tab([
      Text("Click to play"),
      _btn('Play', () => audioCache.play('assets\Images\MP3.mp3')),
    ]);
  }
```

I am new to flutter, for my applications i want play two sounds mode(background sound ,button action sound), after referred from flutter package i have changed code like as above , when i used this widget in my material,i am getting below error,

E/flutter ( 2750): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(181)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 2750): Unable to load asset: assets/assetsImagesMP3.mp3
E/flutter ( 2750): #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:221:7)

Answer (score 0):

Backslash are Windows-specific. Use slashes instead. Android is Unix-based and so is iOS

```
audioCache.play('assets/Images/MP3.mp3')
```

Comment: i have tried the same , still same error coming  @Günter Zöchbauer

Comment: Try `flutter clean`.

Comment: Still same error , seems i missed something in code

Comment: Ups, I missed that. You can't read assets as file. You need to use https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/AssetBundle-class.html